# python: getting modules within a package

Tags: python

I want to provide a dynamic list of modules from within a package. Layout:

```
modules/
    __init__.py
    index.py
    user.py
```

Right now I have a `modulelist` tuple defined statically like so:

```
modulelist = ('index','user')
```

And I then access `from modules import modulelist`

What's the canonic way to provide that tuple (or list) dynamically?

Comment: There is no canonical way to dynamically import modules. The implementor may have imported some in `modules/__init__.py` but there is no way in general to know which modules are even supposed to be imported.

Comment: more specifically, is there a safe way to render a list of the modules contained in the package? in the 'modules' folder in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet using `pkgutil.walk_packages` (docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages):

```
# In your case -- you can however substitute any package
import modules
mod = modules

for _, module_name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(
    mod.__path__,
    prefix=mod.__name__ + '.',
):
    # Do something with module_name
```

I've used this in a couple places in code I've written:

- https://github.com/Yelp/Testify/blob/26a23d46e45cb3849bf61cb4a999a52a837432ca/testify/test_discovery.py#L90-L95
- https://github.com/Yelp/paasta/blob/02edfb5949085ffeb56f90bdc55066cd0de05218/paasta_tools/cli/utils.py#L55-L63